# Set-up Stripe Connect for split payments

Tags: stripe-payments, developer-tools

I have a platform which users register on with their car and then another user can then rent the car for a period of time. When the payment for the rental is received to our company account I need to be able to pay out 80% to the car owner and then pay our company account the remaining 20%.

I have Stripe integrated on my platform and we can receive payments but I don't know how to set up the rest, Stripe support are saying the platform developers need to do it, but the platform developers don't know where they need to do this and tell me I actually need to do it within Stripe myself. Im so frustrated and confused as no one is helping me.

I would be so grateful for some advice and help on if code needs to be put on the platform by the developer and if so what code? Also if there is a link to the correct guidelines.

Thank you in advance! 
Gen

Answer (score 1):

The product you need to use here is called [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect). It allows you to collect payments on behalf of a third-party, send them the funds and keep a portion of it for yourself.

The idea is that you will act as a platform and have your own Stripe account. Car owners will be able to register with your platform and create their own Stripe account that will be connected to your own.

When a customer wants to book a car you'll be able to collect their card details securely and charge them on behalf of the car owner while keeping a portion of the funds for yourself.

This will be a more complex integration though and something that your developers will need to build for you if you're not the developer yourself. You'll use multiple Stripe products such as Connect as mentioned earlier, but also [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) or [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements) to collect card details.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for coming back to me. Yeah, I believe Stripe Connect is the correct thing required here and that's what I have set-up, however, this is not the issue I'm having, apologies if I wasn't very clear in my original message, difficult to explain over text. So we have the checkout set-up already when a customer wants to book a car they log into their profile and on checkout, they add in their bank card details and complete the process. Currently, 100% of that money comes straight into the business account on Stripe, but we need 80% to go to the car owner and 20% to remain.

Comment: Does this make a little more sense? We are having to manually move the 80% of funds to the car owner but I believe Stripe Connect is meant to be able to have something like this happen automatically. My accountant and development team and Stripe support have all been in disagreement on who actually has to set this up as well as my dev team saying they don't know how. So Im very stuck. :) Thank you

Comment: @GenavieveFairbotham yes, you need to look into the documentation for Connect though. It explains how you can set `on_behalf_of` and `transfer_data` for this for example: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges and the same concepts apply to Checkout! But you first need to create those car owners accounts via the API. There's a lot of work beyond "just using Checkout" here. I'd recommend talking to Stripe's support team instead: https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: Thanks so much @koopajah . Let me talk to my dev team and tell them this, because they set up the payments side so should be able to set up the on_behalf_of etc too. I have been talking to Stripe support for over 1 year now and they keep pushing it back on our developers but not actually helping. This issue has been around for a while and I am just frustrated as no one (besides you) has been able to give me a straight answer. Im going to try this though. Thank you! :) Have a great day.